# Is there any way to convert an &str into an AccountId inside a substrate pallet?

Tags: polkadot, rust

Is there any way to convert an &str into an AccountId inside a substrate pallet?

I need this because a evm precompile is interactive with the pallet, and its sending the address (its already in substrate format b58) as a &str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://github.com/hack-ink/array-bytes

```rs
let account_id_32 = array_bytes::hex_n_into::<_, AccountId32, 32>(public_key_str)?;
let account_id_20 = array_bytes::hex_n_into::<_, AccountId20, 20>(public_key_str)?;

// Or you might want to use `[u8; 32]`, `[u8; 20]`.
let account_id_32 = array_bytes::hex2array::<_, 32>(public_key_str);
let account_id_20 = array_bytes::hex2array::<_, 20>(public_key_str);
```

---

If you want `AccountId` you'd better define a trait and implement it in the runtime level.

Because the pallet doesn't know your `AcccountId` type. You don't know how many bytes that you should take.

```rs
// pallet
pub trait Config {
  type Str2AccountId: Str2AccountId,
}

pub trait Str2AccountId {
  type AccountId;

  fn str2accountid(public_key_str: &str) -> Self::AccountId;
}

impl<T> Pallet<T>
where
  T: Config
{
  fn example(public_key_str: &str) {
    let account_id = T::StrToAccountId::str2accountid(public_key_str);
  }
}

// runtime
pub struct StrToAccountId;
impl pallet::StrToAccountId for StrToAccountId {
  type AccountId = AccountId32;

  fn str2accountid(public_key_str: &str) -> Self::AccountId {
    array_bytes::hex2array::<_, 32>(public_key_str)
  }
}

impl pallet::Config for Runtime {
  type StrToAccountId = StrToAccountId;
}
```

Comment: But this is an AccountId32, not an AccountId

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know any method to transform an ss58 to pubkey in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the representation in ss58 format already check this old answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66075924/5964038

```
let account_id: AccountId = AccountId::from_ss58check("AccountSs58Format").unwrap()
```

In case you have the hex representation and want the AccountId, check this old answer from StackOverflow too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983883/how-to-encode-the-hex-string-representation-of-an-account-id-in-substrate-using

```
let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!["d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"].into();
```

And then get the ss58-check string with `to_ss58check()`.

Check the functions of the ss58 codec library [here](https://docs.rs/sp-core/5.0.0/sp_core/crypto/trait.Ss58Codec.html).

Comment: I didn't write this method because `from_ss58check` requires `std`. So, I think he can not use this in the pallet.  :)

Comment: And `hex_literal::hex!` requires a string literal. I prefer to use `array-bytes`. :)

Comment: True, for the pallet your response makes more sense than the from_ss58check