# How can i resolve an error with converting a string into a public key

Tags: pallet, runtime

I am using the following function in my pallet to convert a string into a public key

```
        fn split_publickey_from_input(input: &Vec<u8>) -> T::Public {
            let input_string = sp_std::str::from_utf8(input).unwrap();
            let input_vec: Vec<&str> = input_string.split(":").collect();
            let pub_key = sp_core::sr25519::Public::from_str(input_vec[2]).unwrap();
            T::Public::from(pub_key)
            
        }
```

Unfortunately this works well in the pallet but when i try to build the node with `cargo build --release` i face this error below

```
let pub_key = sp_core::sr25519::Public::from_str(did_vec[2]).unwrap();
      |                                 ^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Public`
```

How can i resolve this error? An explanation of what's going wrong is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's std only. You can't use this in your pallet.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_core/sr25519.rs.html#138-140

```rs
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
impl std::str::FromStr for Public {
    type Err = crate::crypto::PublicError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Self::from_ss58check(s)
    }
}
```

---

And check this: [Is there any way to convert an &str into an AccountId inside a substrate pallet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-str-into-an-accountid-inside-a-substrate-pallet)